# how to create google cloud function with kubernetes client

Tags: c#, function, kubernetes, cloud

Is it possible to create a google cloud function in .NET to run job in kubernetes?
What are the options for doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you asking for something like Google Cloud Run instead? I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I update my question, and mean write google cloud function

Comment: Cloud Functions can be written with .NET, so no issues there. Kubernetes has an API that you can access to add, update, delete, etc. resources within the cluster, so no issues there either.